# Error connecting to IBM Bluemix server in Domino Designer

Tags: xpages, ibm-cloud, xpages-extlib, ibm-cloud-plugin

I am trying to create something in IBM Bluemix.
Stuck at the beginning.
I installed the Extension lib x_15 from openNTF.
In the DDE preferences I selected the UK Bluemix server.
Entered my credentials and pressed the "test connection" button.
A connection error pops-up.
In that dialog there is only.
com/ibm/icu/impl/ICUBinary

Any idea's?
I can connect via the command line cloud foundry. So the username and password is correct.
Also when I try to import the sample app. via Tools - IBM Bluemix Starter Code I get the same error.

Regards,
Peter

Comment: What install+FP level is your DDE at?

Comment: 901, No Fixpack, clean install.

Comment: Try installing latest fix pack (FP5)

Comment: FP5 is retracted due to installation issues. Installing FP4 now. Already upgraded to windows 10 also. No Luck yet

Comment: FP4 installed, same problem

Comment: Removed my notes complete again. Installed clean, FP4 and openNTF ext. lib_15. now I get the error "peer not authenticated"

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the DDE BLUEMIX URL is **api.eu-gb.bluemix.net** because that is needed if you connect against the UK datacenter.

You need to install FP5IF1 that should solve the issue, as Per Henrik Lausten suggested. I got secondary confirmation of this from the Designer team so it should work.
You can download it here http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24037141
or perhaps here 
[Download center link for FP5IF1](http://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?parent=Collaboration%2BSolutions&product=ibm/Lotus/Lotus%20Notes&release=9.0.1.4&platform=Windows&function=all)

Comment: Do you have an English designer?
Also it could be related to if you don't have english letters in your password or username.
Because the text you suggest points to the java ICU Language lib

Comment: Hi Fredrik,  I only use English software. Is there a designer in another language? :-)  The password are only letters and number and no special characters.  I am running the designer in VM Ware Fusion,windows 7 on a macbook pro. But that can not be the problem I guess

Comment: And if you check the menu Help -> Support - View Log or view Trace and check for more information there about the problem.

Comment: In the log some entries of sametime. In the trace i have this

Comment: eclipse.buildId=20131002-1404
java.fullversion=JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 Windows 8 x86-32 jvmwi3260sr16fp4-20150406_242976 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - 20150406_242976
JIT  - r9_20150402_88984

Comment: GC   - GA24_Java6_SR16_20150406_1410_B242976
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en
Framework arguments:  -dir ltr -NPARAMS /authenticate =C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Notes\notes.ini -RPARAMS -personality

Comment: com.ibm.rcp.platform.personality -product com.ibm.rcp.personality.framework.RCPProduct:com.ibm.notes.branding.notes -plugincustomization C:/Program Files (x86)/IBM/Notes/framework/rcp/plugin_customization.ini
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -dir ltr -NPARAMS /authenticate =C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Notes\notes.ini -RPARAMS -personality com.ibm.rcp.platform.personality -product com.ibm.rcp.personality.framework.RCPProduct:com.ibm.notes.branding.notes -data c:/Program Files (x86)/IBM/Notes/Data/workspace -

Comment: plugincustomization C:/Program Files (x86)/IBM/Notes/framework/rcp/plugin_customization.ini

Comment: Try the fp5 install as suggested by Per Henrik and the Designer, ExtLib Bluemix team. I know it has been withdrawn but check my second link to the download center because there is an FP5IF1 that should work.

Comment: ** Update Dec 2, 2015 ** The W32 Notes Standard 901 FP5 client has been removed from Fix Central due to an issue affecting the install process. **

Comment: I know it has been withdrawn but check my second link to the download center because there is an FP5IF1 that should work.

Comment: Found it. Installed and now... the blue mix option in the preferences are gone. Try to get it back by installing the ext. lib again but that does not work :-( .. will try a clean install again from scratch...

Comment: Clean install DDE, install FP5, install OpenNTF Ext.Lib xx_15 and it works! Thanks Fredrik and Per Henrik!